# How to work around Expecting value: JSON error?

Tags: json, python-3.x

This is to extract Google place id. But I'm getting **JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json

service='http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/json?'

while True:
    address = input("Enter location: ")
    if len(address) < 1 : break
    url = service + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor':'false','address':address})
    print('Retrieving',url)
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    print('Retrived',len(data),'characters')
    js = json.loads(data)
    placeid = js["results"][0]['place_id']
    print("Place id",placeid)
```

Input: South Federal University

Expected output:

Place id ChIJNeHD4p-540AR2Q0_ZjwmKJ8

Comment: Can you show us what the JSON looks like?

Comment: I ran the program with your input, when I got to the website I doesnt give any json, it just says "Missing/incorrect key= parameter (it is an easy number to guess)..."